# javascript - how do I assign a link to a sign in button with node

Tags: javascript, node.js

so im trying to link the sign up page with the js page and i have no idea how, this is my forst time web developing so any advice is much much appreciated.
this is from a template i found online, what i want is to fill in the login info and have it say sommething like password and user dosent match?

```
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  <div class='loginBox'>
      <h2 style="color:#ec7079;">Login</h2>
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" size="24">
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input type="text" name="password" size="25">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>Remember me </label><br />
      <button id="buttonRegister">Log in</button><br />
      <a href="/lostpassword">Lost your password</a><br />
      <a href="recipe.html">Back to Homepage</a>
```

```
'use strict';

const path= require('path');
const express=require('express');
const app= express();
const user= require(path.join(__dirname,'./user.json'));
const server= require('http').Server(app);
const port= process.env.PORT || 3100;
const host= process.env.HOST ||'localhost';
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'js')));
app.use('/style', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'style')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')));
app.get('/', (req,res)=> res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'recipe.html')));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'html'))); //if wanna have HTML in one folder
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/login.html')));
app.get('/signup',(req,res)=>res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/signup.html')));
app.get('/lostpassword',(req, res)=> res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/lostpassword.html')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.post('/login', express.urlencoded({extended:false}),(req,res)=>{
  if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  if(user[req.body.username]==[req.body.password]){
    res.render('login',{data:req.body, text:'Log in sucessfully', result:'You are now logged in'});
  }else{
    res.render('login',{data:req.body, text:'Incorrect password!', result:'Go back to login page and try again'});
  }
});
app.post('/sending', function(req,res){
  res.redirect('/');
});
server.listen(port,host,()=>
console.log(`Server ${host} on port ${port}`)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Taco! If you are using another person's code, you need to name your source. What have you tried so far in terms of your solution? Have you looked into tutorials? Thank you!